# join query with jpaTemplate is super slow

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, inner-join

I have a query that looks like this:

```
Query q = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT a FROM ObjectA a JOIN a.objectB b JOIN b.objectC c WHERE a.col1 = :val1 ORDER BY c.val1 ASC", ObjectA.class);
q.setParameter("val1", "my val");
q.setFirstResult(startIndex).setMaxResults(maxNumRecords);
return q.getResultList();
```

This query takes much longer than I expected.
Any thoughts on how to speed this up? Alternative ways to write this?

Comment: Have you try an explain plan on this.  When doing so make sure that you use variables and this may effect your DB's ability to use the proper indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have indexes on a.col1 and c.val1

Comment: We have index on c.val1, but not a.col1.
Would adding index to a.col1 help a lot?

Comment: I suspect it could be slow because of the hydrating of the objects, but I don't know how to query out only certain columns.

Comment: @abcXYZ Yes indeed, anytime you use WHERE, ORDER BY and so on you absolutely need indexes.